# Xrtml And Ruby on Rails, Calendar booking slot 

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to build a time slot calendar whereby a booking manager can create timeslots from a calendar. I have found some examples below:

[Time slot calendar](http://www.phpjabbers.com/time-slots-booking-calendar/demo.php)

[XRTML Calendar Booking](http://www.xrtml.org/demos/calendarclient.aspx?SessionID=xpbo3n3loh)

Was wondering is it possible to have xRTML work with Ruby On Rails. I downloaded the .js file and put this in my assets/javascript folder.

I found that xRTML has its own tags and put the demo code in an index.html.erb. But this did not seem to work.

My index.html.erb file looked like the following:

```
<xrtml:config debug="false">
    <xrtml:connections>
        <xrtml:connection appkey="myAppKey" authenticate="false"
            authtoken="myDevToken" url="http://developers.realtime.livehtml.net">
            <xrtml:channels>
                <xrtml:channel name="myChannel" permission="write"/>
            </xrtml:channels>
        </xrtml:connection>
    </xrtml:connections>
</xrtml:config>


<xrtml:calendar channelid="myChannel" dayonly="false"
    enddate="2011-12-13" handlerurl="./handler/calendarTest.ashx"
    id="calendarXPTO" lang="en" receiveownmessages="true"
    startdate="2011-08-13" target="#divcalendar" userid="userxpto">
    <xrtml:triggers>
        <xrtml:trigger name="myTrigger"/>
    </xrtml:triggers>
    <xrtml:slots>
        <xrtml:slot value="09:00 - 10:00|10:00 - 11:00|11:00 - 12:00|12:00 - 13:00|15:00 - 16:00|16:00 - 17:00|17:00 - 18:00"/>
        <xrtml:slot value="09:00 - 18:00" weekday="Sat"/>
        <xrtml:slot weekday="Sun"/>
    </xrtml:slots>
</xrtml:calendar>
```

I have also considered using Jquery full calendar to help me achieve what I am trying to do. However this is proving to be more difficult than I thought. Is there anything similar out there that is like what I am trying to do

My initial idea is to have some sort of calendar with times listed vertically and have slots horizontally enabling a user to click a plus sign that will create new slots as it were.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xRTML is designed to work with any platform/framework that sends HTML to the the browser so 
there is no limitation about Ruby or Ruby on Rails.
There are four things missing in your code, Djj:

1) your Connection tag still has the values `appkey` and `authtoken` set to the defaults that come with the documentation, you need to use the ones provided in the development kit...

```
<xrtml:connection appkey="myAppKey" authenticate="false" authtoken="myDevToken" url="http://developers.realtime.livehtml.net">
```

2) you are not including the script into your page (maybe you just didn't paste it into your question, but:)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/xrtml.js"></script>
```

3) the Calendar tag requires an HTML container where it is going to be rendered. In the tag, you see target="#divcalendar", that is a Sizzle selector for a div where the calendar's html will be rendered, so you must include, somewhere:

```
<div id="divcalendar"></div>
```

4) the handler for the persistence... this is where things get serious. The Calendar tag, requires a server side handler and a database to deal with the records. so, you have to implement in ruby, a handler for the ajax calls made by the calendar (you can find the documentation for it in http://docs.xrtml.org/markup/calendar.html, in the '3.2 Persistence Data' section). So, when defining the tag:

```
<xrtml:calendar ... handlerurl="path/to/yourhandler" ...></xrtml:calendar>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding for what I'd describe as an in depth and helpful answer. Much appreciated :)